# Custom Check Printing

Tags: check, gnucash

I just downloaded GnuCash, first time user.

I needed to print custom checks, but when I click on the options, all of the custom part is grayed out, non-functioning.

If anyone knows what I need to do that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> I needed to print custom checks, but when I click on the options, all of the custom part is grayed out, non-functioning.

I am assuming that you selected a transaction, then clicked on "File" → "Print Checks ..." in the menu bar to print a check for the selected transaction. To be able to edit the fields, you will need to change the "Check format" to "Custom". Result:

[image: GnuCash Print Check options]

[image: GnuCash Print Check custom format]

Note: I am using GnuCash 3.8.